# BeautifulSoup Troubleshooting involving flat HTML hierarchy and next_sibling loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

so I have a flat hierarchy HTML as such:

```
<div class="caption">
  <strong>July 1</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Top Gun</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Millennium Park"
  <br>
  "Amenities: Please be a volleyball tournament..."
  <br>
  <em>Captain Phillips</em>
  <br>
  "Location: Montgomery Ward Park"
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>July 2</strong>
  <br>
  <em>The Fantastic Mr. Fox </em>
```

And I'm getting tripped up right from the start with my code .. am I using find_sibling incorrectly or what else is the issue here that I can't get anything to return when I run `print title`? Thanks guys.

```
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

URL = 'http://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/chicago/free-outdoor-summer-movies-chicago'

html = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

root = soup.find_all("strong")
for row in root:
    sibling = row.next_sibling
    while sibling and sibling.name != "strong":
        if sibling.name == "em":
            title = sibling.text
        sibling = sibling.next_sibling
print title <---- still not getting the movie titles under tag<em>
```

Comment: This code just spins forever in an infinite loop. I think you want a `sibling = sibling.next_sibling` in there somewhere. Although I don't know why you aren't just looping over `row.next_siblings` instead.

Comment: Anyway, either way I fix that, I get 'The Fantastic Mr. Fox` as the output, at least with your sample input. And `Ironman 3` when I access the URL.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your sample input is an incomplete fragment, and appears to be pretending to be HTML5 but not being valid HTML5, so… which BeautifulSoup version, which parser, which version of the parser (and, if lxml, which libxml2 version)?

Comment: @abarnert hah, im not sure how to even check my BS version! and im not using lxml (should I be?), my whole code is just that. the html is from inspect the element of the URL(http://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/chicago/free-outdoor-summer-movies-chicago)

Comment: You can check the BS version with `bs4.__version__` from inside Python, or `pip list |grep -i beautifulsoup` from outside (unless you're on Windows, or didn't install it with `pip`). The docs (which alecxe's answer links to) show you how to set a parser, and what it means to do so. `html.parser`/`HTMLParser` comes with Python; the other two, you have to `pip install`, and the same `pip list` will show you their versions if you installed them. `libxml2` is a C library that `lxml` needs; the details for that depend on your platform.

Comment: fantastic! @abarnert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setting an underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) to `lxml` (needs to be installed), or `html.parser` helped me to solve the problem (as usual, all credits to @abarnert), demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> 
>>> URL = 'http://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/chicago/free-outdoor-summer-movies-chicago'
>>> html = urlopen(URL).read()
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all('strong'))
81
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all('strong'))
81
>>> len(BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib").find_all('strong'))
0
```

Note that if you don't specify the parser explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` will choose the one automatically:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

I suppose, in your case the choice was `html5lib`, and, as you see in the demo, there are problems with it, no `strong` tags found and hence, you don't see the `title` printed.

---

Also, following @abarnert's notes, you need to exit the inner loop once you hit the next `strong` tag:

```
root = soup.find_all("strong")
for row in root:
    for sibling in row.next_siblings:
        if sibling.name == "strong":
            break
        if sibling.name == "em":
            print sibling.text
```

Prints:

```
A League of Their Own
It's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad World
Monsters University 
...
Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs 2
Best in Show
Ironman 3
Sean Cooley is Thrillist's Chicago Editor and is still mad that Ben Affleck is the new Batman. Follow him @SeanCooley.
```

Comment: If his problem is that `title` is empty, this isn't going to solve the problem. (And, in fact, nothing is going to solve the problem, because it can't be reproduced in the first place…)

Comment: @abarnert I agree, you last comment is actually the key problem here. Thanks.

Comment: @abarnert it would be fair to give credits to you for your initial proposal to change the parser. Consider providing an answer.

Comment: Well, you did the research on testing all three parsers to figure out which one he's probably using and why it didn't work.

Comment: alecxe good to see you again! you've answered a ton of my questions over the past couple days so I remember you lol. 

What would be the best way to exclude that last line though?

Thanks so much, both you and @abarnert are lifesavers!

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce glad to see you again and thank you for the interesting question! Slice the list of next siblings: replace `row.next_siblings` with `list(row.next_siblings)[:-1]`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @alecxe why's the `if not sibling: continue` part needed?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce good point, it was not needed, updated. Thanks.